# linga purana section i.54.9-12 does this prove scientific error in hinduism?

Tags: puranas, shiva-purana, science, linga-purana, vayu

SPEED OF SUN MOVING AROUND EARTH
Linga Purana Section I.54.9-12 ;
“…Similarly when the sucker of waters (i.e. the sun) moves about in the middle of Puskara the mountain to the north of Manasa, he traverses a thirtieth part of the earth in a Muhurta (48 mts). Understand this number in yojanas travelled in a Muhurta. The speed of the noble souled sun per Muhurta is three million one hundred and fifty thousand yojanas…” Tr. Board of Scholars, edited by J.L. Shastri

Vayu Purana I.50.119-121 :
“When the sun passes through the middle of the sky, it traverses one thirtieth of the diameter of the earth in a Muhurta (forty eight minutes). In regard to the distance traversed in Yojanas, know that it is three million one hundred and fifty thousand in full. This is the distance traverses by the sun in one Muhurta.” Tr. G.V. Tagare

1 Muhurta = 48 minutes

1 Yojana = 8 miles (as per Hindu translators of Puranas)

3,150,000 Yojana*8 miles = 25,200,000

25,200,000/48 = 525,000 i.e. speed in one minute

525,000*60 = 31,500,000 miles per hour

According to modern science,
“The Sun’s orbital speed around the Galaxy: ~200 km/s (720,000 km/h, 450,000 mph) The speed of the ground beneath your feet, as a result of the Earth’s rotation: 1000 km/h (600 mph) at the latitude of Sheffield (53 degrees); it goes up to 1670 km/h (1000 mph) at the equator.”

Comment: Puranas are encyclopedic in nature and tell us what the ancients were thinking at the time they were last revised. There is no need to learn science from such ancient texts.